# Hash read/write/delete functions

Tags: javascript, url

Here is my JavaScript function to manipulate the hash:

```
var hash = {
    get: function(key){
        var lh = location.hash;

        if(lh.charAt(0) === "#"){
            lh = lh.slice(1);
        }

        var pairs = lh.split("&");
        var obj = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++){
            var pair = pairs[i];
            if(pair.indexOf("=") > 0){
                pair = pair.split("=");
                obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            }else{
                obj[pair] = 1;
            }
        }
        return typeof key !== 'undefined' ? obj[key] : obj;
    },
    set: function(key, value, cb){
        var newHash = this.removeKey(key);

        if(newHash.length > 1){
            newHash += "&";
        }
        newHash += key + (typeof value != 'undefined' ? "="+value : "");
        var url = location.href.split("#")[0] + (newHash !== "#" ? newHash : "");

        history.pushState(undefined, document.title, url);
        if(cb){
            cb();
        }
    },
    del: function(key){
        var newHash = this.removeKey(key);
        var url = location.href.split("#")[0] + (newHash !== "#" ? newHash : "");

        history.pushState(undefined, document.title, url);
    },
    removeKey: function(key){
        var string = location.hash;

        if(string.charAt(0) !== "#"){
            string = "#" + string;
        }

        var regex = new RegExp("[#&]"+key+"(=[^&]+|)", 'gi');
        string = string.replace(regex, "");

        if(string.charAt(0) === "&"){
            string = "#" + string.slice(1);
        }

        return string !== '' ? string : '#';
    }
};
```

I am trying to make it as light as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streamlined code for `get`:

```
get: function(key){
    var lh = location.hash.replace(/^#/, "");
    var pairs = lh.split("&");
    var obj = [], pair;

    for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++){
        pair = pairs[i].split("=");
        if (pair.length === 1) {
            pair.push(1);
        }
        obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }
    return typeof key !== 'undefined' ? obj[key] : obj;
},
```

I also don't see why there's a callback passed to `.set()`?  There's no async operation and the callback is executed at the end of the function with no args so the caller could just put that same code right after the `.set()` call.  There doesn't seem to be any reason for a callback argument.

Comment: That really is a lot better. Thanks a lot.
P.S. I took out the callback. I just had that there to test something.